# Sending DELETE request in a link in nodejs express app

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, rest, express

I have a route which accepts DELETE requests, and I know that with Express you can add

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
```

to a form that sends a POST request to the url.

However, how would you do this with a link instead of a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported for GET requests:

[`methodOverride()`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js) only checks `req.body` (POST arguments) and request headers - neither can be set for a regular link (you *can* however set custom headers in AJAX requests even if they use GET).

This make senses since otherwise it could be a major issue even when using CSRF tokens. You can never know when a browser will decide to prefetch a link - so GET requests should *never* perform actions such as deleting things.

If you really need it and do not care about the drawbacks, consider writing a custom function:

```
function methodOverrideGET(key) {
    key = key || "_method";
    return function methodOverrideGET(req, res, next) {
        if (req.originalMethod != req.method) {
            // already overridden => do not override again
            next();
            return;
        }

        req.originalMethod = req.method;
        if (req.query && key in req.query) {
            req.method = req.query[key].toUpperCase();
            delete req.query[key];
        }
        next();
    };
};
```

Now you can `.use(methodOverrideGET)` *after* `.use(methodOverride)` and then simply add `_method=DELETE` to the query string.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I was looking into `methodOverride` earlier. I'm going to use it for deleting sessions, so I don't think the security implications are that huge?

Comment: Yeah, in this case it's pretty harmless. But for something like this I'd use AJAX anyway...

Comment: and I think I'll need to explicitly check for the route for deleting sessions in the custom `methodOverride` middleware so that someone doesn't inject the query string parameter into the url for another DELETE route, and tries to do some funky CSRF attack

Comment: I'd say AJAX is less work :p (anyway, since your question is answered please consider accepting the answer)

Comment: You may be right. Out of curiosity, what frameworks/libraries do you like to use for your AJAX solutions? Pure javascript, jquery, backbone.js?

Comment: Look at my [golden tag badges](http://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster?tab=badges&sort=class) and you have your answer (if you are lazy: it's jQuery).